# Springboot app not connecting to rabbitmq

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am using springboot `2.0.5.RELEASE`, integrating a rabbit connection with `spring-boot-starter-amqp` dependency.

Rabbit Configuration:

```
import org.springframework.amqp.core.AmqpTemplate;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.EnableRabbit;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitConfig {

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost(rabbitmqHost);
        connectionFactory.setPort(rabbitmqPort);
        connectionFactory.setUsername(rabbitmqUsername);
        connectionFactory.setPassword(rabbitmqPassword);
        connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(rabbitmqVirtualHost);
        connectionFactory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);
        CachingConnectionFactory cacheConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        cacheConnectionFactory.setRequestedHeartBeat(rabbitmqRequestedHeartBeat);
        cacheConnectionFactory.setChannelCacheSize(channelCacheSize);
        return new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

When I am starting up the application, I am not seeing any attempt to connect to rabbit server.

The only snippet in logs pertaining to rabbit is:

```
{Bean 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitBootstrapConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3b504de] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)","logger_name":"org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker"}
{Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e1e10baf] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)","logger_name":"org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker"}


{SECURITY ALERT: this trust manager trusts every certificate, effectively disabling peer verification. This is convenient for local development but offers no protection against man-in-the-middle attacks. Please see https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html to learn more about peer certificate verification.","logger_name":"com.rabbitmq.client.TrustEverythingTrustManager"}
{SECURITY ALERT: this trust manager trusts every certificate, effectively disabling peer verification. This is convenient for local development but offers no protection against man-in-the-middle attacks. Please see https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html to learn more about peer certificate verification.","logger_name":"com.rabbitmq.client.TrustEverythingTrustManager"}
```

What is the reason that app is not attempting to connect to rabbit. I have another app with same configuration for  rabbit servers, and it does attempt to connect to rabbit.

Comment: Does the other application that works, uses the same version of `spring-boot` ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same version 2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

> `CachingConnectionFactory cacheConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);`

You should not be creating a new connection factory within the template bean definition.

If you want to customize the connection factory, it must be a bean itself.

A connection won't be established until you try to interact with the broker (by sending or attempting to receive a message).

Comment: moved the connectionfactory to a separate bean, was still same issue; had to remove `JmxAutoConfiguration` from exclude configs at SpringBootApplication, and it is working.